# Como almaceno un valor de un DropDownList en una variable?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Buenos Dias,

Con el siguiente código de C#, genero un DropDownList.

```
 public void CargarViaSolicitud()
    {
        Class.EntidadConexion cnn = new Class.EntidadConexion();
        cnn.Conexion().Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Stp_Drops", cnn.Conexion());
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Opcion", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 3;

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        this.ddlViaUtilizada.DataSource = dt;
        this.ddlViaUtilizada.DataValueField = "ViaSolicitudId";
        this.ddlViaUtilizada.DataTextField = "ViaSolicitud";
        this.ddlViaUtilizada.DataBind();

        cnn.Conexion().Close();
        ddlViaUtilizada.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Seleccione Vía... "));
    }
```

Lo que necesito es capturar ese DataValue y DataText que el usuario seleccion, para enviarlo a una tabla en base de datos.

Agradeceria su Ayuda.

Comment: `ddlViaUtilizada.SelectedItem.Value` para el valor seleccionado

Comment: Gracias @lois6b si me funciono

Comment: nada. Ahora estoy en el móvil. Si para cuando pueda escribir la respuesta nadie lo ha publicado la mando yo. Saludoa

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar este código.

```
private void DdlViaUtilizada_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string valorSeleccionado = ddlViaUtilizada.SelectedItem.Value;
    string TextoSeleccionado = ddlViaUtilizada.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, solo necesito capturar el Value...

Answer (score 1):

Podrías agregar un handler al evento SelectedIndexChanged de la siguiente manera:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ddlViaUtilizada.SelectedIndexChanged += DdlViaUtilizada_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }

    private void DdlViaUtilizada_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ddlViaUtilizada.SelectedItem.Value
        //ddlViaUtilizada.SelectedItem.Text
    }
```